# Why can't I craft a cleaver?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

[image: Crafting window with cleaver parts]

I can't make the cleaver with paper tool rod, paper large plate and a manyullyn large blade....Why?

Comment: I think this is something you could have just looked up on a wiki.

Answer (score 4):

You've used paper tool rods, but what you actually need are **tough** rods. Check the wiki [here](http://tinkers-construct.wikia.com/wiki/Cleaver) for help crafting TC tools.